# Context Sensitive help for AbstractGraphicalEditPart(GMF)

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gmf

the problem is simple: To add Context Sensitive Help i followed the standard steps, but once i try to link the BLOCKS to the CONTEXT IDs with SetHelp() from IWorkbenchHelpSystem. The frist argument should be either a Control(swt)   or IAction.
void setHelp(Control control, String helpContextId);. How can i refer to Control from a damos.dml.Block object type ?
[org.eclipselabs.damos.dml.blockTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY5W3.png)

FYI 
I've tried and visited all the content of these sites

- http://rajakannappan.blogspot.com/2009/05/context-sensitive-help-in-eclipse.html
- https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_context.htm&cp=2_0_19_1_2
- https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_commands.html

The display and search methods are working correctly but I just need to set the help and not display it so that only upon calling Help (F1 or ctrl+F1) the context help is shown.

Thanks.
After trying I thought maybe this workaround would get me the same result but NADA.

```
private Block getBlock() {
        EObject semanticElement = resolveSemanticElement();
        if (semanticElement instanceof Block) {
            Block block = (Block) semanticElement;
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().search(block.getType().getName());
//PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(?, Activator.HELP_VIEW); Cannot cast block directly to Control 
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp(Activator.HELP_VIEW);
                return block;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

 @Override
protected NodeFigure createMainFigure() {
    blockFigure = new BlockFigure();
    // OB: java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F1 is wrong, use SWT.F1
    blockFigure.setFocusTraversable(true);
    blockFigure.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
    blockFigure.addMouseListener(new MouseListener.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent me) {
            blockFigure.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    blockFigure.addKeyListener(new KeyListener.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.keycode == SWT.F1) {
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().search(getBlock().getType().getName());
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayHelp(Activator.HELP_VIEW);
            }
        }
    });
    return blockFigure;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `damos.dml.Block`? The workbench help only works on UI objects, is this a UI object?

Comment: org.eclipselabs.damos.dml.Block I am as clueless as you about it. I have been handed a tool which uses rcp and has a diagram editor where you can drag and drop this so called Blocks to make a SPS diagram that will be translated to a program.

Comment: Since the original programmer meant that once i can derive the SWT Control behind the Blockfigures wich are part of forming the Block. I take it they are considered as a UI Object.

Comment: As you have seen you can only set help on an SWT control of some sort, so you need to understand the controls that this editor uses.

Comment: Ok how about this, i can add a KeyListener to my Blockfigures, but it is not an swt Event but a draw2d Event. (org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure.class) But the call event.keyCode = java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F1 for the help key F1 does not seem to work as i tought !

Comment: Avoid FocusControl may work for AW but from experience this poses problems. Maybe try this  https://www.javatips.net/api/EPF-Composer-master/1.5/plugins/org.eclipse.epf.authoring.ui/src/org/eclipse/epf/authoring/ui/editors/AbstractDiagramEditor.java

Answer (score 0):

```
   public String getSelection() {
            String blockName = "SelectBlock";
            EObject element = null;
            EditPart part = getDiagramEditPart();
            EditPartViewer viewer = part.getViewer();
            List selectedList = viewer.getSelectedEditParts();
            try {
                GraphicalEditPart editPart = (GraphicalEditPart) selectedList.get(0);
                BlockEditPart blockPart = (BlockEditPart) editPart;
                viewer.getProperty("BlockFigure");
                NodeImpl node = (NodeImpl) blockPart.getModel();
                element = node.getElement();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ISelection selection1 = viewer.getSelection();// EURêKA

            if (element instanceof Block) {
                Control control2 = getGraphicalViewer().getControl();
                blockName = ((Block) element).getType().getName();
                return blockName;
                // return part.getParent().getSelected();
            }
            return "SelectBlock";
        }
```

i have the possiblity to select a block type CTRL+F1 and voila the Help Definition of said Block is shown.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I dont think the code needs any explanation it seems quiet simple how i use getGraphicalViewer.getControl(); to gain the Control over the selected element, and to identify the selected element i use the EditPart Object to extract the node. If the answer is incomplete feel free to edit it.